# How to quickly test saved code in Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a script in Sites that processes POST parameters. It is published as service and allows anonymous access. I have trouble testing my code since the new Versions and Libraries feature was introduced. Changes I make are (obviously) not reflected in my service until I explicitly save a version and publish. I don't see how 'development mode' could work for me, since the anonymous access bit is essential. Saving and publishing a new version every time I change something is very, very time-consuming though. Does anyone have suggestions/ideas for a workaround to this? Am I overlooking the obvious?

Thanks,
arno

Comment: Not sure why anonymous access to the service would be a problem. Maybe this helps: To reduce the auth problem, I run a (empty) function from the GAS editor before reloading the web page.

Comment: the problem is that I need to process a POST call from a external site, that cannot complete when in development mode (403) because that does not allow for anonymous access. And I need the external call in order to be able to do a call back for verification. Have the feeling I am not seeing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an edge case that wasn't considered when developing the new versioning system for webapps. For now you're best bet is to just create a new version, but if you feel strongly you can [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to allow for anonymous access to the development URL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will file such a request.